# How to use a Union to store 2 different structs in 1 C array

Tags: c, struct

I would like to create one array to store 2 types of C structs - `Employee`, and its 'child',  `Manager`. I created a union `Person` to hold either of them and then tried creating an array with it, but it doesn't work. How can I get such an array to work? The relevant code is below.

```
 typedef struct {    
    char name[20]; 
    double salary;
    } Employee;

//Manager struct inheriting from employee struct
typedef struct {
    Employee employee;   
    int bonus;
} Manager;  

typedef union{ 
       Employee e;
       Manager m;
      } Person;
Manager boss;
Employee harry ;
Employee tommy;
Person staff[]; 

int main(void)
{
...
boss = newManager(...);
  harry = newEmployee(...);       
  tommy = newEmployee(...);
```

I couldn't get the next line to work, I tried many things.

```
  staff[3] = {boss, harry, tommy};
```

Comment: Technically your union is not necessary, because as a manager contains an 'Employee' as first member, any manager instance can indeed be accessed as an Employee. It wouldn't make the code very clean, however :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
staff[0].manager = boss;
staff[1].employee = harry;
/* ... */
```

Or maybe:

```
Person staff [] = {
    {.manager = boss},
    {.employee = harry},
    /* ... */
};
```

But ask yourself: how will you know later if `staff[x]` is a manager or a mere employee ?

Comment: Thanks, `staff[0].m = boss;` was able to compile. I had tried something similar before, but I guess there had been a different issue then.